# MS SQL Server - Match tables and their unrelated records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

This might be something more common than I can imagine, but I have been bending my mind around it for months in total failure.

Two tables are fed by quite unrelated systems about the same things. But they use different identifiers for such things and I would like to find a way to merge these tables into one where each record in A would match its "most equivalent" record in B.

Both databases look like that:

```
A.sessionID     A.itemSeq   A.dateSessionStart
1870            32          2017-12-20 16:00:00     
1871            55          2017-12-23 17:00:00
1871            56          2017-12-23 17:00:00
1871            57          2017-12-23 17:00:00
1873            24          2018-01-05 15:00:00
1873            25          2018-01-05 15:00:00
1878            36          2018-01-12 15:30:00



B.sessionID     B.itemID    B.dateItem
520             1           2017-12-20 16:04:32     
522             1           2017-12-23 17:15:04
522             2           2017-12-23 17:32:26

523             2           2018-01-05 15:41:06
523             3           2018-01-05 16:02:21
524             1           2018-01-12 15:37:55
```

And this is part of the table/view I would like to obtain:

```
A.sessionID     B.sessionID     A.itemSeq       B.itemID        A.dateSessionStart      B.dateItem
1870            520             32              1               2017-12-20 16:00:00     2017-12-20 16:04:32 
1871            522             55              1               2017-12-23 17:00:00     2017-12-23 17:15:04
1871            522             56              2               2017-12-23 17:00:00     2017-12-23 17:32:04
1871            522             57              NULL            2017-12-23 17:00:00     NULL
1873            523             24              2               2018-01-05 15:00:00     2018-01-05 15:41:06
1873            523             25              3               2018-01-05 15:00:00     2018-01-05 16:02:21
1878            524             36              1               2018-01-12 15:30:00     2018-01-12 15:37:55
```

It seems that the dates and the sequence in each table might allow a kind of relation by similarity. However:

- There is no guarantee that there will be enough records in B to match records in A and vice-versa. This is what I tried to show by the missing third record in B for 2018-12-23. There are some "missing records" in A as well. Actually, both tables have records with absolutely insane dates (free typing inputs, I guess).
- Both tables somehow use sequential IDs, but under different rules.

I would describe my knowledge in SQL queries as basic-to-intermediate. I have tried to create a subquery under SELECT, matching by DATEDIFF between the datetimes from both tables, looking for an example in all SQL books I have, looking for a similar question here... but I have got no success so far.

Thanks!

Fabricio Rocha

Brasilia, Brazil

Comment: What is the logic that you want to use to match rows from both tables ? Please post the SQL query you have so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you've got is you've loaded all this data into a RELATIONAL database management system; a device that works by having clearly defined relationships between tables

And you don't have a clearly defined relationship

As best i can make out, you assert that "the order of the items from the sequence IDs is roughly the same from each system, and the times are approximately the same"

Ok, so let's assume these systems are both noting when podcasts occur and one of the systems has a faulty clock that only reports the hour but other than that it's a working clock that keeps time

It looks like B's clock is about 3 minutes ahead of A's, given that you assert a 16:02 from b is equivalent to a 15:00 from a, but a 16:04 from b is equivalent to a 16:00 from A

Let's turn this data into something relatable:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
  SELECT
    dateSessionStart,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dateSessionStart ORDER BY sessionId, itemSeq) rn
  FROM a
) a
FULL OUTER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    DATE_ADD(hour, HOUR(adj), CAST(CAST(adj as DATE) as DATETIME)) as dateSessionStart,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CAST(adj as DATE), HOUR(adj) ORDER BY sessionid, itemid) rn
  FROM(SELECT *, DATEADD(minute, -3, dateItem) adj FROM b) b
) b
ON a.dateSessionStart = b.dateSessionStart and a.rn = b.rn
```

If you want more detail run the subqueries in isolation but basically this query adjusts the time of the b records back by 3 minutes each then strips the minutes and seconds off by just adding the hour of the time to the date (midnight)

Separately but using these adjusted hour precision times, an incrementing counter is established with row_number. The counter restarts from 1 every time the hour changes. The counter increments in order of the other sequential ids. We thus don't care that the sequence ids are not equivalent, we just use them to define order for making a pseudo join key. The join relationship is this established on the hour-precise time plus the restarting counter

Note, ghisbwas written on a cellphone with no testing - there might be small typos/syntax errors, missing brackets etc - let me know any errors you get while running it and I can help out, but I've got a busy day so feel free to have a crack at then yourself and suggest an edit to my answer if you fix them

Partitions aren't hard; think of them like a separate grouping querythat is automatically joined back to the main data:

```
SELECT name, age, city, AVG(age) OVER(PARTITION BY city) FROM t

SELECT name, age, city, avgagecity 
FROM
  t
  INNER JOIN
  (SELECT city, AVG(age) as avgagecity FROM t GROUP BY city) c on c.city = t.city
```

The above two queries are conceptually the same; in one we group up by city and avg the age, join it back to the main table. Voila

The other we ask the db to partition the data by city, average the age. The db will auto-join its bucket of city:avgage back implicitly. When the t.city is "San Fran" then the db goes to its bucket of cities, looks for san fran, pulls the average age, sticks it on the row

PARTITION BY here is thus effectively GROUP BY x JOIN x

For things where the order matters, like row_number, an ORDER BY is necessary, for fairly obvious reasons. In these kind of queries PARTITION BY is used to divide up the results, but note that there isn't any grouping because row_number isn't an aggregating operation. Here in an ordered operation (that needn't have a partition at all) any partition specifies when to start over as if the data is in a new counted group. A couple of other common ordered operations are RANK and DENSE_RANK. Like row number but they refer to winning places, so equal values (a race was run, 1 person won with a mile in 3:59, then two people ran the mile in 4 minutes. They're are ranked equal 2nd. RANK skips numbers if people tied, so 1st, equal 2nd 2nd, 4th (there is no 3rd place, it was skipped because of the tied 2nd place. If 3 people tied, 4 4th place would skip etc). DENSE_RANK doesn't skip

Comment: Thanks, Jard, I'll study and try that. I've been thinking that ROW_NUMBER might help but I still don't know much partitions and window operations. Actually these are tables about votings and sessions from a legislative house, fed by two unrelated systems, both depending on the operator in charge (and there is the problem of manual, free input). The time difference between session records is quite variable; sometimes something around 3h. I am not really sure SQL alone is enough for such a task, but I would still like to try every possibility.

Comment: Manual alignment then, methinks.. or fix the systems that supply the data, to supply better data :) Partitions aren't hard. I'll add a bit of info